# Securing MediaWiki LocalSettings.php on nginx

Tags: nginx, mediawiki

I am trying to secure my LocalSettings.php. First, I found the nginx user (`www-data`) using `top`, did `chown -R www-data:www-data wikidir`, and then tried to do `chmod 600` on `wikidir/LocalSettings.php`. The breaks the site, however. The site only works if LocalSettings.php is world readable, which is something I don't want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any useful errors in the log?

Comment: Nothing of significance in error.log it seems. There is one error relating to a favicon file, but its only happened once while I tried changing permissions several times.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to run the PHP code?

Comment: Nginx with fast cgi. I have PHP 5. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your fastcgi processes are running as a user other than `www-data`; you'll want to change this configuration so that it runs as `www-data` (there are security implications to this, since that user can then write to everywhere that `www-data` can, but that's probably what you want with a mediawiki install).

Where this is configured depends on how fastcgi was installed - the [nginx fastcgi example](http://wiki.nginx.org/FcgiExample#Spawning_a_FastCGI_Process) has it set in an environment variable in the init.d script, but your setup may vary.  If you can't find where to change that, then let us know how fastcgi was installed and we can assist.

Comment: This lead me to the solution. I have two FastCGI running in the background. One is under user `www-data` the other `webrootadmin`. I did `chown -R webrootadmin mywiki` and now I am able to change permissions without breaking the site. Thank you!